# Scala: return element using if inside map function

Tags: scala, list, functional-programming

I have a list of type `Person` in scala like this:

```
Person("P1", "Person 1", List(WorkStation 1, WorkStation 2))
Person("P2", "Person 2", List(WorkStation 1, WorkStation 3, WorkStation 4, WorkStation 5))
Person("P3", "Person 3", List(WorkStation 3, WorkStation 5))
Person("P4", "Person 4", List(WorkStation 2, WorkStation 4))
```

I want to code a function that receives this list and a parameter `ws: WorkStation.WorkStation` (it is a case object) and then I want that function to return the first element `Person` which has `ws` in it's list.

For example, if `ws` was `Workstation 3` I wanted to return the list entry with `Person 2`.

I thought about doing something like this:

```
def setPerson(ws: WorkStation.WorkStation, totalPersons: List[Person]): Person = {
    totalPersons.map { p => if (p.workstations.contains(ws)) return p }
}
```

However, this doesn't compile, because it gives me an error and it is not the most functional approach for sure.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `collectFirst`:

```
totalPersons.collectFirst{ case p if p.workstations.contains(ws) => p }
```

Or `find`:

```
totalPersons.find(_.workstations.contains(ws))
```

See [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html) for more information.

Comment: This helped me a lot, however, trying to use your `Find` solution, the function returns `Some(Person(...))` and not `Person(...)` as it should. What tweak should I do to accomplish what I want?

Comment: What it returns is an option, if you are sure you can always find an element from the list that satisfies your predicate, then you can use `get` method to get the `Person` like `totalPersons.find(_.workstations.contains(ws)).get`, if you are not sure, use `getOrElse(...)` to return a default value if the element is not found.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
totalPersons.find(elem => elem.workstations.contains(ws))
```

or

```
totalPersons.find(_.workstations.contains(ws))
```

the 1st is more readable (specially for scala rookies), but the 2nd is common syntactic sugar used